# A query on a BST that takes neither maximum nor minimum time

Tags: algorithm

No idea if this is better off on MathOverflow.

A dynamic binary search tree (I assume that it can keep the tree strictly balanced, e.g. red-black, also the BST shall have n keys and each key shall be queried exactly once) can take minimum O(n) for a "good" instance (e.g. a sorted query) or maximum O(n log n) for a "bad" instance (e.g. a bit-reversal sequence).

If this is easier for you, this is an *almost* equal geometric setting, courtesy by Demaine: Draw n points in the plane (no equal x or y coordinates!). For each pair of points, draw the axis parallel rectangle with these two points as corners. If no other point is inside this rectangle, you own its diagonal, but you can't own two diagonals if the two rectangles overlap in a way that at least one corner of one is strictly inside the other. (Sharing a corner is OK! The somewhat ugly condition is necessary, as otherwise with two parallel diagonals of points, you can own O(n^2) diagonals.) Again, can you own *between* O(n) diagonals (the points lie on a diagonal) and O(n log n) (the points lie chaotic)?

I'm now sitting on my master thesis for almost two years, and like to namedrop an example that needs an "in-between" value, say O(n loglog n). Do you know one? (A reference would be even better.)

Disclaimer: The work is almost done, it's just for a insignificant subordinate clause, but it's driving me mad that any of the umphty  wacky sequences I have come up with falls either into the maximum or minimum case. Also, it could come extremely handy for any follow-up work. If you can't come up with one off-hand, I drop the question altogether. After all, I already have written 150 pages... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the tree hold the numbers `0..(n-1)`.

Let `m` be an integer close to `log(n)` and relatively prime to `n`.

Your data set is the multiples of `m` modulo `n`.  That is, `m, 2m, ..., 0`.

You can easily verify that all of the numbers appear once in the sequence.  There are `m ≈ log(n)` times you wrap around, each of which causes a query to take `log(n)` for an overhead at the boundaries that is easily `o(n)`.  And otherwise for `n - m` times what you have to go is go up `log(m)` levels, then down `log(m)` levels to get to the value that is `m` away.  These steps take `O(log(m)) = O(log(log(n)))` each, for overall time `O(n log(log(n)))`.

Good enough?

Comment: Sounds convincing and very elegant, I try it out. Possibly different standard algorithms may have different runtime (as you know, move-to-root can have epic fails), but that wasn't my question anyway. Shall I cite you as "btilly, pers.comm., SO" or is it "common knowledge"?

Comment: @HaukeReddmann You can cite me as Ben Tilly.  I have no idea how common the knowledge is, but I figured it out on my own.

Comment: Tested and accepted :-) A followup question: Call each interval between the wraparounds a phase. Assume you reverse the query order in all even phases. Is the cost still n loglog n? I'm not so sure about that...

Comment: @HaukeReddmann The cost should still be `O(n log(log(n)))`.  After all you're taking n steps of size `log(n)` and the steps cost `log(log(n))`.

Comment: Good to know. (The punchline is: Again by Demaine, for the *optimal* algorithm it doesn't matter if you ask for keys j at time f(j) or the other way around, but not necessarily for *some* algorithm. For your example, rotating seems to change nothing, as step m with wraparound just turns into step m' with wraparound, but with zigzag things change enormously after space/time swap.

Comment: Completely forgot to ask - the value holds for a *static* BST, right?

Comment: @HaukeReddmann Yes, static.  Assuming optimal binary structure.